# Why can't I pack this Tkinter Menu widget?

Tags: python, xml, tkinter

I'm building a GUI in Tkinter as part of my application and I've written a class "XMLMenu" which subclasses "Menu" but I'm receiving a TclError when I try to pack it. Here's what it looks like:

```
class XMLMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self,master,text, **kw):
        Menu.__init__(self,master, kw)
        #Irrelevent code in which I read an XML file to build the menu
        self.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
```

And I'm receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "xlistr\gui.py", line 62, in create
    app=constructor(root)
  File "xlistr\gui.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.menu=xmlMenu_by_filename(self,"xlistr/data/feMenu.xml")
  File "xlistr\gui.py", line 23, in xmlMenu_by_filename
    return XMLMenu(master,read_file(filename))
  File "xlistr\gui.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1806, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
TclError: can't pack ".26194928.31816720": it's a top-level window
```

Comment: I fixed your indentation.  Please check to make sure I did it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menus are not placed with a geometry manager, but configured in the corresponding window:

```
class XMLMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self,master,text, **kw):
        Menu.__init__(self, master, kw)
        master.config(menu=self)
        # ...
```

Comment: @user1472751 Is `master` a widget different than a `Tk` or a `Toplevel`? In that case you cannot do this.

Comment: master is a subclass of Frame. So I guess not.

Comment: @user1472751 Then you have to configure it in the window where that Frame is packed (i.e. `master.winfo_toplevel().config(menu=self)`)